# What is the function of "exhausts" in this context? Does "more than exhausts" refer to "the psychic knowledge"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, grammaticality-in-context, functions

What is the function of "exhausts" in this context? Does "more than exhausts" refer to "the psychic knowledge"?

> Both Kate Fox Jencken and Margaret Fox-Kane died in the early 'nineties, and their end was one of sadness and gloom. The problem which they present is put fairly before the reader, avoiding the extremes of the too sensitive Spiritualist who will not face the facts, and the special-pleading sceptics who lay stress upon those parts of the narrative which suit their purpose and omit or minimize everything else. Let us see, at the cost of a break in our narrative, if any sort of explanation can be found which covers the double fact that what these sisters could do was plainly abnormal, and yet that it was, to some extent at least, under their control. It is not a simple problem, but an exceedingly deep one which **exhausts**, and more than **exhausts**, the psychic knowledge which is at this date available, and was altogether beyond the reach of the generation in which the Fox sisters were alive.

from [The History of Spiritualism, Vol. I by Arthur Conan Doyle](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html)

Comment: The text is hopelessly dated (both linguistically and philosophically), but the "extremes" are those "arguments / presentations" that Conan Doyle thinks overstate their cases. He himself is trying to give the impression that "the Truth" lies somewhere ***in between*** people who dismiss Spiritualism out of hand and those who credulously believe claims that are manifestly untrue. It seems that "the problem" is *deciding whether Spiritualism  is true or not*. Apparently Conan Doyle believes there's such a thing as "psychic knowledge" - but for some reason it's unable to resolve that problem.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica that was a good help for me to understand the text.

Comment: I see from the frontispiece that Conan Doyle was *Président d'Honneur de la Féderation Spirite Internationale, President of the London Spiritualist Alliance*, and *President of the British College of Psychic Science*. So although his writing style *purports* to be that of a "dispassionate observer / investigator", he's obviously seriously committed to his belief in such things. As such, you should assume that all his text here is "loaded" (he's a highly skilled writer attempting to influence what you think, by fair means ***or*** foul).

Comment: FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica great. do you want to say that he is not impartial? but as far as i read this book i understood that he considers both sides of the matter.

Comment: I too think the author was biased. The passage in your [recent question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/243023/why-does-the-author-say-the-information-was-correct-but-after-that-he-says-th) states *"...abnormal power was shown by reading the contents of a letter in Mr. Funk's pocket."* Considering the immense skill of the detective Holmes in the novels, this conclusion suggests that ACD **wanted** to believe that the only way the letter could be read was by psychic means.

Comment: ...perhaps the origin of Holmes and his ability to extract or deduce the tiniest scrap of information was ACD's interest in spiritualism, and the technique of [**cold reading**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_reading) which "mediums" employ to garner information which they "can't know" (apart from stooges and by outright fraud).

Comment: I recall thinking more than once before (when scanning various excerpts you've posted here) that the text was curiously "partisan", but I figured that was just a side effect of the fact that ACD earned his living writing *(**fictional**)* tales of the supernatural. Now I see he actually held high office in several organisations dedicated to promoting such things, it's obvious he really believed in them, and was quite prepared to use his literary skills to further the cause. I feel let down, like when I discovered what nonsense L Ron Hubbard believed in (which ruined his fiction for me! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica i must say that sir arthur conan doyle was a great spiritualist and it is not a bad thing to be a spiritualist.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica i do not think that doyle did these things for making money.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica i want to say that you must read the whole history of spiritualism and then judge it. doyle said that religious and scientific people want to destroy spiritualism, i think the present world needs more spirituality.

Comment: Oh, well if you want to believe in stuff like that, I suppose it's your privilege. All I'm saying is ACD's writing style is very much "persuasive". He's using every trick he knows to make it seem as if he's dispassionately examining the "evidence", whilst making sure that his readers will agree with his predisposition to believe in the supernatural. It's always useful to know if someone you're reading or listening to is specifically trying to influence your thinking in subtle ways by using their superior language skills.

Comment: (I'm all for saying people should be more "spiritual". I just don't buy into fanciful notions about "Spiritualism", ghosts, black magic, etc.)

Comment: @solesoul whilst you could be right, [**spirituality**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/spirituality) and [**spiritualism**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/spiritualism) are quite different things.

Comment: @yes. i know that the core of spiritualism and doyle writings is communication with the dead.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica let me tell you that i am a young and inexperienced person. i am grateful for your hepls. i say that there are more things that i must learn, more books that i must read, more people that i must know. it is too soon for me to support a specific side but i am sure that materialism is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "exhaust", as used here, means to use up, to use all that is available. Like you might say, "Buying a new car exhausted all the money in my bank account."

So the writer is saying that people have some knowledge of psychic phenomena, but this knowledge is limited and incomplete, so that understanding whatever magic these sisters did goes beyond our understanding of psychic phenomena. It "exhausts our knowledge", it uses all the available knowledge and we still don't understand.

Comment: thanks for your answer and thanks for not commenting and judging the beliefs of author or me rather than be serious and giving a helpful answer.

Comment: @solesoul As a Fundamentalist Christian, I often get slammed on StackExchange when I occasionally express my beliefs or opinions. I don't want to do the same thing to others. :-)

Comment: @ Jay dear jay i do not know you. but i want to tell you that conan doyle said a beautiful sentence in his book. he said lets be friends. lets ruin the walls and become united. he hoped that spiritualism will unite the people some day in future.

Comment: i think that history of spiritualism is full of golden points about enlightenment and it is completely against bigotry.